# Git Repo Submoduling another repo that contains a submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a test utilities Git repo called testutils. This contains tools that help me test all my other repos. I have another Git repo called analytics which has the testutils as a submodule.

```
analytics
 |__ testutils
```

Now I want to create another Git repo called ABC that makes use of the analytics repo and because I need testing, should have testutils as a subdirectory of ABC. This is my desired structure

```
ABC
 |__ analytics
 |__ testutils
```

I do not want testutils among the analytics subdirectories.

How do I achieve this in Git? If what I am asking is not the accepted best practice, what is the best practice in this situation?

Comment: The easiest way is to have 2 separate repos: `analytics` and `testutils`. Update your script to do testing with those 2 repos stand-alone.

Comment: But then there will be duplication of testing utilities in analytics. Is there a way to add a submodule without adding its submodule?

Comment: you do not have to clone the other submodule. avoid using '--recursive' flag in the git operations.

Comment: I tried that. It seems to work. With reference to the above setup the ABC/analytics folder contains an empty testutils subfolder. Can you write it up as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: If `analytics` *needs* `testutils` to build / run, you cannot "not" have it as a subdirectory. If it is only used for running tests against the `analytics` code, you can "skip" it by not recursively initializing submodules, but how much time and space are you saving? I'd just not worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good way in git to do it. However, if you avoid recursively cloning/updating the submodules, you will end up just with the 'testutils' subdirectory inside 'analytics' with not much contents in there.

To completely get rid of the directory you would need to forget about submodules and do some scripting around separate anlytics and testutils. Linux soft links could be a good solution as well.